# Is "established convention" a tautology?

Tags: word-usage

*Established convention* looks like a tautology to me, though it could be found in many serious sources. Should I avoid it in technical writing and use just *convention* instead?

> The Independent: Green as I am, I learned something new here, something which I suspect would be news to a lot of people, journalists or otherwise: if a reporter has a friendly chat with the Queen, it's a matter of **established convention** that her remarks remain private.

> The Guardian: My aim is to turn **established conventions** on their heads.

> The New York Times: However, when it comes to connected services, there are no **established conventions**.

Comment: Is "new convention" an oxymoron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I would not consider **established convention** a *tautology*. From Lexido:

> *[tautology](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tautology)*: The saying of the same thing twice in different words, generally considered to be a fault of style (e.g., they arrived one after the other in succession).

**Established convention** doesn't say the same thing in different words. I would say though that *established* is *superfluous*. From Lexico:

> **[superfluous](https://www.lexico.com/definition/superfluous)**: Unnecessary, especially through being more than enough.

Comment: A downvote on this answer? Really??? How is **established convention** a tautology? How does it say the same thing in different words? A *convention* by definition is *established*, so *established* is both superfluous and redundant, but that a tautology does not make.

Comment: It's not redundant.

Comment: @HotLicks Fair point. I've edited the answer to remove *redundant* and added a definition of *superfluous*. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: So it seems that "established" isn't really necessary but provides some emphasis and works as a "safety belt" in edge cases when we may erroneously think about something like "new conventions", as Hot Licks pointed out.

Comment: @johnc.j. That's a fair summary.